# What is a Samsaran Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Samsaran Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| SAMSARAN Words™ | Not SAMSARAN Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PIPELINE | CONDUIT |
| AVERAGE | MEDIOCRE |
| ITEMIZE | ENUMERATE |
| ACCEPTABLE | ADEQUATE |
| INHABITANT | RESIDENT |
| ANTEJURAMENTUM | PLEA |
| LIVELINESS | ZESTINESS |
| SPOKESWOMEN | SPOKESMEN |
| UNINSULTING | RESPECTFUL |
| VIOLATIONAL | REBELLIOUS |
| ANTICAPITALIST | COMMUNIST |
| WEATHER-BEATEN | DILAPIDATED |

Or, in a CSV:

```
SAMSARAN Words™,Not SAMSARAN Words™
PIPELINE, CONDUIT
AVERAGE, MEDIOCRE
ITEMIZE, ENUMERATE
ACCEPTABLE, ADEQUATE
INHABITANT, RESIDENT
ANTEJURAMENTUM, PLEA
LIVELINESS, ZESTINESS
SPOKESWOMEN, SPOKESMEN
UNINSULTING, RESPECTFUL
VIOLATIONAL, REBELLIOUS
ANTICAPITALIST, COMMUNIST
WEATHER-BEATEN, DILAPIDATED
```

These are not the only examples of Samsaran Words™, many more exist.

**What makes a word Samsaran?**

Comment: I had no idea, but when I looked at the answer, I was definitely impressed! $(+1)$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Key:

> It's in the vowels

Explanation:

> Samsara words contain multiple sets of vowels which are repeated:
>  p**I**p**E**l**I**n**E** (IE-IE), **A**v**E**r**A**g**E** (AE-AE), sp**O**k**E**sw**O**m**E**n (OE-OE), **A**nt**E**j**U**r**A**m**E**nt**U**m (AEU-AEU), **A**nt**I**c**A**p**I**t**A**l**I**st (AI-AI-AI) etc.

Note:

> As @el-guest pointed out, some of the non-samsaran words also fit this pattern (adequate, dilapidated), but they contain other vowels that are not repeated. Samsaran words contain exclusively repeated vowels.

Title:

> Perhaps they are called Samsara words because Samsara is a repeated cycle of birth and death

Comment: Great answer! But adequate and dilapidated also follow your rule....

Comment: @El-Guest Adequate and Dilapidated have additional vowels as well (not exclusively the repeated vowels)

Comment: wEAthEr-bEAtEn does not follow the same pattern, because there is a 'th' between the first one, and only a 't' between the second EA_E.

Comment: Also, anticapitalist has A _ _ I ... A _ I .. A _ I. Spacing is different again?

Comment: And inhabitant: I _ _ A ... I _ A.

Comment: @El-Guest oh! Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. Clearly I was too specific in saying that the spacing needed to be equal. I'll remove it from my answer

Comment: That's it! Good job :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is that:

> **Every vowel of a Samsaran word occurs in the word more than once.**

This allows the corner case

> W**e**ath**e**r-B**e**at**e**n, which contains 4 Es and two As.

Also, the word Samsaran is itself a Samsaran word (kinda... more on that below).

> *I phrased my answer this way in order not to specify the number of vowels required. Why, you may ask?*

Funnily enough,

> The condition "is a Samsaran word" is not completely defined. **Must there be two or more vowels?** There are no counterexamples to prove it, and no examples preclude it... Is "book" a Samsaran word? For that matter, is "tsktsks" a Samsaran word?

*I didn't mean to swoop User omzrs' answer. I arrived at my solution independently, then looked at the spoilers on that answer, only to find that I had been beaten by about 6 hours. However, I posted mine because I felt I had a more precise definition and something important to add to the discussion.*

Comment: This is actually a clever and very clean solution! +1